# How can I verify that all select boxes have a selected option through JavaScript or JQuery or...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, select, verification

I have 2 select boxes on a page with a variable number of options in them.

For instance:

```
<fieldset>
    <label for="fizzwizzle">Select a Fizzwizzle</label>
    <select name="fizzwizzle" id="fizzwizzle" size="10">
        <option>Fizzwizzle_01</option>
        <option>Fizzwizzle_02</option>
        <option>Fizzwizzle_03</option>
        <option>Fizzwizzle_04</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <label for="fizzbaggot">Select a Fizzbaggot</label>
    <select name="fizzbaggot" id="fizzbaggot" size="10">
        <option>Fizzbaggot_01</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
```

I would like to verify that both of these select boxes have a selected option.  My initial thought is to simply use JQuery but I can't seem to figure out how to do that.  My attempts so far have been futile but I have the following code that I think should work with the missing link.

```
function verify_selectboxen_selection() {
    var allSelected = true;

    $('select').each(function() {
      /* if select box doesn't have a selected option */
            allSelected = false;
            break;
    });

    if (!allSelected) {
        alert('You must select a Job and a Disposition File.');
    }
    return allSelected;
}
```

Seems simple enough.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In jQuery you can use the `:selected` selector to get the total options selected. This number out to match the number of select's themselves:

```
if ($("select").length === $("option:selected").length) {
  // they match
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly with a few modifications. My code looks like `if($('select').length === $('select option:selected').length)`. No parens on the last length.  Edit that and I can accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Tim: Sorry about the parens - `$.width()` and `$.height()` have ruined me ;)

Comment: Except for `select multiple`, and `select` with no child `option`​s, this will *always* be true. A select-one box always has a selected option even if the user has not interacted with the control.

Comment: @Tim: A select with an option automatically has an option selected - the first option.

Comment: @Jonathan: I understand that. That's not the part I'm disputing. The solution you posted works. If I don't select anything in the select boxes, then I correctly identify that nothing was selected using your method. Is this something JQuery tries to be intelligent about, perhaps?

Comment: @Tim: The point @bobince is making is that a selection is made regardless if you do the selecting or not. The first option will be selected by default. If this is alright with your project, then there are no worries :)

Comment: @Jonathan: That's what I'm saying. When I don't select anything and submit the form, the code says that nothing is selected. Am I missing something about the behaviour you and @bobince are describing? I would expect, as @bobince says, that your test would always return true because the select boxes come in with a selection each.  That's not the behavior I'm seeing.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. If I have a non-empty, non-multiple select, `$('option:selected').length` is always 1 for me. Would be interested to see a test case if you can make that not happen!

Comment: Finally had some time to put this demo together.  Tested and verified in both Firefox and Chrome.  What am I missing? http://j.mp/9i7dur

Comment: Spotted it. The problem was that I forgot to mention that I set the size attribute on the select tags. I added an example to the demo page I put together. Sorry for the confusion. http://j.mp/9i7dur

Comment: Interestingly enough, I discovered as well that Chrome 4.0.249.89 (38071) doesn't seem to honor the `size` attribute unless it's 1.  Otherwise it makes the size = the number of options. Maybe. I didn't pursue it much further.

Comment: @TimVisher: Your demo seems to work for me. Each demo requires the user to select an option from both `select` elements. The last set of `select` elements implicitly select the first `option` element once the page loads. What's the problem?

Comment: No problem at all. What I was referring to was the confusion between myself and @bobince and you. As far as I can tell, the reason @bobince thought your solution wouldn't work was because I had forgotten to mention that I had set the size attribute to be greater than the number of options. When that is set, @bobince's concerns seem to disappear. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @TimVisher: Hehe, no problem. Sorry for causing you so much distraction here. Glad to hear your problem is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to verify that both of these select boxes have a selected option

It's not possible for a (non-`multiple`) `select` box *not* to have a selected option! If you don't declare `selected` on one of the `option`​s, the browser will automatically select the first option.

So: `return true;` :-)

If you want to have an ‘unselected’ initial state, you'd have to include a no-option `option` for it, usually the first one:

```
<select name="fizzbaggot">
    <option value="" selected="selected">(Select a fizzbaggot)</option>
    <option>foo</option>
    <option>baz</option>
    <option>bar</option>
</select>
```

Then you can check whether a different option to that one has been selected, either by saying:

```
$('select').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val()!=='')
        allSelected= false;
});
```

Or, if you might want to use the empty string as a valid value, you can just look at the index of the selected option:

```
$('select').each(function() {
    if (this.selectedIndex===0)
        allSelected= false;
});
```

Comment: Should it not be `$(this).val()!==''` as you're setting allSelected to false if it is an empty string

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [:selected selector](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) for this.

```
var unselected = [] 
$('select').each(function(){
    if (0 == $(this).find('option:selected').length) {
        unselected.push(this.id);
    }
});

if (unselected.length != 0) {
    // unselected contains the ids of non-selected select boxes
}
```

Or you could check their values with [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/). This presumes that you have a default option with no value (ie empty string value).

```
var unselected = [] 
$('select').each(function(){
    if ('' == $(this).val()) {
        unselected.push(this.id);
    }
});

if (unselected.length != 0) {
    // unselected contains the ids of non-selected select boxes
}
```

Comment: Good answer. It's just no where near as compact. Thanks for the effort, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function checkSelects() {
        return $("select :selected").length == $("select").length;
    }

alert(checkSelects());
```